# How to get CLIENT timezone offset into razor view to display time converted from UTC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, timezone

I am doing the following in a Razor view using MVC 5:

```
foreach(var item in Model)
{
    @{string dt = item.DateExpiring.ToString();} @dt
}
```

I need the @dt variable to be displayed as the CLIENT's local date time.
My idea was to get the client's local timezone offset (in minutes) using Javascript, and pass it to the item.DateExpiring value, converting on the fly, such that I could change the above to read:

```
@{string dt = item.DateExpiring.AddMinutes({someJavascriptVariableHere}).ToString();}@dt
```

Two questions:

1. Is this possible?
2. How to do it? (meaning, how to resolve/convert JS to the double I need)?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: C# code executes way before in server. Your javascript code executes later when the browser receives the response (result of executing c# code) from server.

Comment: you can send the timezone from the client side through this code : 
new Date().getTimezoneOffset()

Comment: Ok, So an adjustment to this question.

Can I somehow send, or obtain, the timezoneoffset from the browser (client) when the actual MVC Controller is called, so that I could then calculate the proper time?

For instance
If I call http://website.com/showlist, which would return a list of times.


How to do I:

1. Get the timeZoneOffset from the client browser and use it in the controller, so that I can adjust the time in the response?

Again. Thanks in advance for suggestions/help.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to display datetime in local, please check here
[UTC on server - local time on client](https://forums.asp.net/t/1896918.aspx?UTC%20on%20server%20local%20time%20on%20client)
In your case:

```
foreach(var item in Model) {
<script type="text/javascript">
  var strDate = new String('@item.DateExpiring.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt") UTC');
  var localTime = new Date(strDate);
  document.write(localTime.toLocaleString());
</script>
}
```